# Many-to-many relations in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, many-to-many

I have an issue with many-to-many relations.

I have 3 model classes:

1. Article - >>> Item
2. Keyword - >>> Keyword
3. TableForRelation between Articles And Keywords - >>> ItemKeywords

With Entity Framework Core, I write these 3 classes and they work fine

```
public class Item
{
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string Content { get; set; }

      public virtual ICollection<ItemKeyWords> ItemKeyWords { get; set; }
}

public class KeyWord
{
       public int Id { get; set }
       public string Text { get; set; }

       public virtual  ICollection<ItemKeyWords> ItemKeyWords { get; set; }
}

public class ItemKeyWords
{
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        public virtual Item Item { get; set; }

        public int KeyWordId { get; set; }
        public virtual KeyWord KeyWord { get; set; }
}
```

Question is: how can I tell Entity Framework if `Keyword` exists do not put that in keyword table and just create a relation to that in ItemKeywords table.

[database uml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pLEj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

before to add a `KeyWord` to `Item.ItemKeyWords` you have to try to load it from `context.Set<KeyWord>()`.

If the load results on a null, then do as actually.

If the load != null then add the loaded value.

Comment: i did that and worked for me .thx  , is any better way exist?

Comment: if you know the id of the keyword, you may use it to construct a KeyWord entity and attach it to the context. Then you use the attached entity to add the keyword to the item. Doing so you avoid a hit to the db.